# Почему нельзя передать данные в поле?

Tags: javascript, json

Вот здесь переменная `datatime` является результатом парсинга `json`'a. В консоль она выводится правильно (проверено).

```
$('datatime').html(datatime);
console.log(datatime)
```

Однако, в само поле с таким `id` значение не передаётся

```
<p>Time: <span id="datatime">0</span> </p>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не верно указываете селектор

```
$('#datatime').html(datatime);
```

Comment: Такая глупая ошибка. Спасибо)